# How to enable autorefresh of structure view in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I force refresh in structure view or enable autorefresh in Pycharm. After any code update clicking on function does not work anymore (should jump to function code). Only possibility is to hide and show view but it loose context and I need search function name again what is bad idea with larger code.

[image: PyCharm Structure View]