# How to refresh Structure view in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

My `PyCharm` structure view does not automatically update when I change the actual script in the editor. For example, I remove a function `getFoo` altogether and save the file but it still continues to appear in the structure view. I was looking for a way to refresh it but, short of closing and reopening the file, I wasn't able to.

Is there a setting that I should change to enable automating structure view refresh or can I at least do it manually (there is no Refresh option in the right mouse click and <kbd>F5</kbd> didn't work either)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39559612/3001761; sadly, it seems that nobody knows

Comment: that question has no answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> keyboard shortcut. This will reload all files from disk.

Alternatively, you can also click on the "File" menu in the top menu bar and select "Reload All from Disk" to achieve the same result.